# Trying to Change Background Image on Multiple Divs "OnClick"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to setup 3 Sections with seperate buttons within each section.  The buttons will change the background image of a div within it's specific section.  I've got it working, however when one section is activated it clears out the background image on the other sections?

Here is my script:

```
<script>
function changeImage(img){
    document.getElementById("store").style.backgroundImage = 'url(/Strat/img/stores/'+img+')';
    document.getElementById("busit").style.backgroundImage = 'url(/Strat/img/schools/'+img+')';
    document.getElementById("busit2").style.backgroundImage = 'url(/Strat/img/maps2/'+img+')';
}       
</script>
```

Comment: can you please show us the relevant html related to that piece of javascript code? (also, where is the changeImage function called specifically?)

Comment: Based on your description, you'd want 3 functions - one for each button click and each function would only change the background of that one section. Your codes shows one function that changes all 3 sections.

Comment: Here is an example of the links I'm using to switch the background image

Comment: <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" id="3.7" onclick="changeImage(this.id)">
                        CAFES & RESTAURANTS</a>

Comment: id being the name of the background image

Answer (score 1):

The change function affects all the three images when triggered. And since the img value for each of it is unique it clears the other two divs on updating the third one.
Solution: Try using if else and separate the image change operation by matching the img value in the condition.

Comment: There are 3 distinct elements being affected. Setting the background image of one of them would not clear the others. What is more likely is that the 3 DOM elements overlap and the background image that winds up being seen is the one with the highest `z-index`.

Comment: Sounds like it could work.  Just not sure how to implement the if else part?

Comment: function changeImg(img){ if(img == "uniqueId1"){<code to change first bg>} else if (img == "uniqueId2"){<code to change first bg>} so on and so forth... }

Comment: @ScottMarcus he has got 3 distinct sections for 3 distinct images so there is no point of z-index

Comment: We don't have enough information to know that. Depending on the layout, we could have overlap.